# Get rid of the [hack] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [hack](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hack) seems barely useful, more like a meta tag. It's used for [hacking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hacking), but not strictly in the sense of security threats, but also "hacking" something together.

Should we remove the "hack" tag from questions not related to security? Or should we just nuke it altogether?

Comment: I think the term hack is very ambiguous in computing these days..

Comment: @SimonSheehan, even if it was not ambiguous, it still adds nothing

Answer (score 13):

I say we...

## Burninate IT!!!

[image]

And then:

## Smash IT!!!!

[image]

## INTO OBLIVION!!!!

Comment: Paper Mario... I miss my N64. :)

Answer (score 1):

I say we **burninate** [it](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hack) *again*...

Comment: Guess we'd need to flag the question to have it marked `[planned]`